# Open port on a gcloud machine for a jenkins slave connection

Tags: jenkins, google-compute-engine

I have a VM instance on google cloud, it is a Windows 2008 R2, I have already set the fixed port that I should use in order to connect my slave Manage Jenkins->configure global security ->enable security-> and set a TCP port for JNLP slave agents.

I have already set Manage Jenkins->configure system-> Enable Security and select a fixed port

I have created the slave with this configuration

Remote Root directory "C:\Jenkins\"
Launch method: "Launch slave agents via Java Web Start"

On google cloud VM instance I have created this firewall rule

Source Ranges:
23.XX.XX.XX

Allowed Protocols or Ports:
tcp:Same_Fixed_Port_From_Jenkins

I have even turned off the Windows Firewall

When I access Jenkins and Launch the .jnpl file it gets connected, however in jenkins the slave is not being displayed as online, the fixed port is open on server side, but I'm not able to open the port on the gcloud machine that is going to be my server slave.

What do I need to do in order to open this port and have access from outside.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

have you checked that your jenkins slave on the google cloud VM instance has a public external or ephemeral IP assigned to it?  Did net test (Ping or Tracert, etc) from 23.x.x.x to your Jenkins slave on google cloud vm instance work?